# A simple question about a cauchy integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $L$ be a closed simple contour in the complex plane, denote the interior and exterior domains respectively by $D_+$ and $D_-$. I need to prove that if $f(z)$ be analytic in $D_-$ and $z \in D_+$ , then $$\int_L \frac{f(\tau)}{\tau-z} d \tau = 2\pi i f(\infty)$$ Any hints/answers are appreciated

Comment: Cauchy's Intergal Formula maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma=1/(\tau-z)$, so that $d\sigma=-d\tau/(\tau-z)^2 =  -\sigma^2\,d\tau$ and so $-\sigma^2\,d\sigma= d\tau$.

Then $f(\infty)$ is the value of $\sigma\mapsto f(\tau)=f\left(z+\dfrac1\sigma\right)$ at $\sigma=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much ! there is still a subtlety here, The contour $L$ in $\tau-$plane gets mapped to the contour $L'$ in the $\sigma-$plane by the transformation $\sigma = \frac{1}{\tau - z}$, we need to know that $\sigma=0$ belongs to the interior of $L'$ (which is easy to see), and also $f(z)$ be analytic in the interior of $L'$, which is again intuitively clear ...  How can I rigorously argue about that?

Comment: The contour $L$ is the image of a compact space (the circle) under a continuous function; therefore it is compact and hence bounded.  So there is some number $A$ such that $L$ lies in the set $\{z: |z|<A\}$.  Therefore $L'$ is in the set $\{z:|z|>1/A\}$.  Thus $0$ is in the interior. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The thing that needs to be analytic in the interior of $L'$ is $z\mapsto f(1/z)$.  You can cite the chain rule.  I assume you intended $f$ to be analytic at $\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$